# Using python to scrape ASP.NET site with id in url

Tags: python, asp.net, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the search results of this ASP.NET website using Python requests to send a POST request. Even though I use a GET request to get the requestverificationtoken and include it in my header I get just get this reply:

```
{"Token":"Y2VgsmEAAwA","Link":"/search/Y2VgsmEAAwA/"}
```

which is not the valid link. It's the total search results with no defined arrival data or area as included in my POST request. What am I missing? Who do I scrape a site like this that generates a (session?) ID for the URL?

Thank you so much in advance to all of you!

My python script:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.Session()

# GET request  
gr = r.get("http://www.feline.dk")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(gr.text,"html.parser")
auth_string = bsObj.find("input", {"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})['value']
#print(auth_string)
#print(gr.url)

# POST request
search_request = {
    "Geography.Geography":"Danmark",
    "Geography.GeographyLong=":"Danmark (Ferieområde)",
    "Geography.Id":"da509992-0830-44bd-869d-0270ba74ff62",
    "Geography.SuggestionId": "",
    "Period.Arrival":"16-1-2016",
    "Period.Duration":7,
    "Period.ArrivalCorrection":"false",
    "Price.MinPrice":None,
    "Price.MaxPrice":None,
    "Price.MinDiscountPercentage":None,
    "Accommodation.MinPersonNumber":None,
    "Accommodation.MinBedrooms":None,
    "Accommodation.NumberOfPets":None,
    "Accommodation.MaxDistanceWater":None,
    "Accommodation.MaxDistanceShopping":None,
    "Facilities.SwimmingPool":"false",
    "Facilities.Whirlpool":"false",
    "Facilities.Sauna":"false",
    "Facilities.InternetAccess":"false",
    "Facilities.SatelliteCableTV":"false",
    "Facilities.FireplaceStove":"false",
    "Facilities.Dishwasher":"false",
    "Facilities.WashingMachine":"false",
    "Facilities.TumblerDryer":"false",
    "update":"true"
    }


payload = { 
    "searchRequestJson": json.dumps(search_request),
    }


header ={
"Accept":"application/json, text/html, */*; q=0.01",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language":"da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
"Connection":"keep-alive",
"Content-Length":"720",
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=ebkmy3bzorzm2145iwj3bxnq; __RequestVerificationToken=" + auth_string + "; aid=382a95aab250435192664e80f4d44e0f; cid=google-dk; popout=hidden; __utmt=1; __utma=1.637664197.1451565630.1451638089.1451643956.3; __utmb=1.7.10.1451643956; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1451565630.1.1.utmgclid=CMWOra2PhsoCFQkMcwod4KALDQ|utmccn=(not%20set)|utmcmd=(not%20set)|utmctr=(not%20provided); BNI_Feline.Web.FelineHolidays=0000000000000000000000009b84f30a00000000",
"Host":"www.feline.dk",
"Origin":"http://www.feline.dk",
#"Referer":"http://www.feline.dk/search/Y2WZNDPglgHHXpe2uUwFu0r-JzExMYi6yif5KNswMDBwMDAAAA/",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
 }

gr = r.post(
    url = 'http://www.feline.dk/search',
    data = payload,
    headers = header
    )

#print(gr.url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(gr.text,"html.parser")
print(bsObj)
```

Comment: Any help guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiples tries, I found that your search request is misformatted (need to be URL Encoded and not JSON), and cookies informations are overwrited in headers (Just let session make the work).

I simplified the code like that and I get the desired result

```
r = requests.Session()

# GET request  
gr = r.get("http://www.feline.dk")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(gr.text,"html.parser")
auth_string = bsObj.find("input", {"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})['value']

# POST request
search_request = "Geography.Geography=Hou&Geography.GeographyLong=Hou%2C+Danmark+(Ferieomr%C3%A5de)&Geography.Id=847fcbc5-0795-4396-9318-01e638f3b0f6&Geography.SuggestionId=&Period.Arrival=&Period.Duration=7&Period.ArrivalCorrection=False&Price.MinPrice=&Price.MaxPrice=&Price.MinDiscountPercentage=&Accommodation.MinPersonNumber=&Accommodation.MinBedrooms=&Accommodation.NumberOfPets=&Accommodation.MaxDistanceWater=&Accommodation.MaxDistanceShopping=&Facilities.SwimmingPool=false&Facilities.Whirlpool=false&Facilities.Sauna=false&Facilities.InternetAccess=false&Facilities.SatelliteCableTV=false&Facilities.FireplaceStove=false&Facilities.Dishwasher=false&Facilities.WashingMachine=false&Facilities.TumblerDryer=false"

gr = r.post(
    url = 'http://www.feline.dk/search/',
    data = search_request,
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)

print(gr.url)
```

Result :

```
http://www.feline.dk/search/Y2U5erq-ZSr7NOfJEozPLD5v-MZkw8DAwMHAAAA/
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gaetan . I feel really dumb - I thought the problem was much more complicated. Again, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kantium for your answer, in my case, i found that the RequestVerificationToken was actually generated in a JS script inside the page.

1 - Call the first page that generates the code, in my case it returned something like this inside the HTML:

```
<script>
    Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.add_invokingRequest(function (sender, networkRequestEventArgs) {
        var request = networkRequestEventArgs.get_webRequest();
        var headers = request.get_headers();
        headers['RequestVerificationToken'] = '546bd932b91b4cdba97335574a263e47';
    });
  
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", '546bd932b91b4cdba97335574a263e47');
        },
        complete: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
    });

</script>
```

2 - Grab the RequestVerificationToken code and then add it to your request along with the cookie from set-cookie.

```
 let resp_setcookie = response.headers["set-cookie"];
 let rege = new RegExp(/(?:RequestVerificationToken", ')(\S*)'/);
 let token = rege.exec(response.body)[1];
```

I actually store them in a global variable, and later in my Nodejs Request i would add this to the request object:

```
headers.Cookie = gCookies.cookie;
headers.RequestVerificationToken = gCookies.token;
```

So that the end request would look something like this:

[image]

Remember that you can monitor requests sent using:

```
require("request-debug")(requestpromise);
```

Good luck !